# Bash script, read timeout screws up prompts

Tags: linux, bash

With script below if I hit return, everything works OK. and everything is as normal when I exit.

However, if instead I wait for the timeout to fire,  then I get the echo(s) I would expect but when exiting and returning to the terminal prompt. The linux prompt gets all screwed up and I get multiple terminal prompts on the line and I cannot see commands I type in.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -t 5 -e -p "INFO: Do you want to do more stuff? [n]: " RESPONSE
if [ "$RESPONSE" != "y" ] ; then
  echo "INFO: Not doing anything anymore"
else
  echo "INFO: doing more stuff"
fi
echo "INFO: completely done"
exit 0
```

Any idea what I need to do in the script to ensure it all returns to normal when I exit?

I've change it now and the problem goes away:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -t 5 -p "INFO: Do you want to do more stuff? [n]: " RESPONSE
if [ $? -ne 0]; then
   echo
fi
if [ "$RESPONSE" != "y" ] ; then
  echo "INFO: Not doing anything anymore"
else
  echo "INFO: doing more stuff"
fi
echo "INFO: completely done"
exit 0
```

it appears the -e(using readline) was causing me a problem, don't completely understand why. Running on Centos 6.8

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me, what seems to be the exact issue, can you describe it in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Its just an extra newline that you get in the first case when you enter an input. If the problem is just how the output looks like, you can always add an extra newline after read:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -t 5 -e -p  "INFO: Do you want to do more stuff? [n]: "$'\n' RESPONSE
if [ "$RESPONSE" != "y" ] ; then
  echo "INFO: Not doing anything anymore"
else
  echo "INFO: doing more stuff"
fi
echo "INFO: completely done"
exit 0
```